# <form> element not working in IE but will in chrome

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, internet-explorer, input

This it will create a message with all the input values in email using chrome, but not in IE and I can't figure out why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Name Entry</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <div>
 <br/>
  <form method="post" 
  action="mailto:cgi55@yahoo.com?subject=from_unit4"  
  enctype="text/plain" 
  style="border: 1px solid #0040ff;
    width: 400px;
    height: 60px;
    align: center;
    background: #ffff00;
    text-align: center;"
  >
 <br/>
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear">
 </form>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work on IE. I just tested on IE11, it prompted me twice and opened Outlook (my default client) message window.

Comment: Did it fill in the message body of the email with Name="yourname"?

Comment: No because you don't have it defined in the mailto. Where is the name supposed to go in your code?

Comment: `mailto` as you probably have figured out isn't cross browser.  There isn't really a way to fix this to my knowledge.